# Pass argument to webapi having a List property

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, rest-client

I have a web api which accepts a class as argument (MyClass). In which a property is of type list. How shall i pass the argument so that the web api receives a list in that property field.

When i pass **Id=1&Name=ABC&MyList=[{AnotherClassName : "The Name"}]** in the POST body using REST client, i am getting the values only in Id and Name field. How shall i send the params in POST body, so that i receives a List of "AnotherClass" in the "MyList"

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<AnotherClass> MyList { get; set; }
}

public class AnotherClass
{        
    public int AnotherClassName { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at Example 7 here: https://damienbod.wordpress.com/2014/08/22/web-api-2-exploring-parameter-binding/.  Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the JSON like this

```
{"Id":1,"Name":"abc","MyList":[{"AnotherClassName":1}]}
```

actually you mase a mistake in MyList object. The property **AnotherClassName** data type is `int` and you are passing it to `string value` and also enclose are your JSON to braces `{....}`.

The better way you should use [NewtonSoft.JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) to convert your object to json before sending.

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();

mc.Id = 1;
mc.Name = "abc";
List<AnotherClass> acl = new List<AnotherClass>();
acl.Add(new AnotherClass { AnotherClassName = 1 });

mc.MyList = acl;

var serializedData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(mc);
```